# Why does Restlet on GAE says Component is NULL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

On every request made to the Restlet resources, I see the following logs in Google App Engine Logs

```
21:38:50.059 javax.servlet.ServletContext log: ExampleAPIs: [Restlet] ServerServlet: component class is null
21:38:51.568 javax.servlet.ServletContext log: ExampleAPIs: [Restlet] Attaching application: com.example.api.ExampleAPIConfig@68ec99 to URI: /example/v1
```

**Why does it say Component is null?** 
I agree that I did not define Components rather used ServerResources and mapped them to the router in the Application class. **But thats how it is supposed to be done as per the Restlet GAE Edition documentation.**

Application class for wiring routes

```
public Example extends Application {
    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        router = new Router(getContext());
        CorsService corsService = new CorsService();         
        corsService.setAllowedOrigins( new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("http://example.com")));
        corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);
        getServices().add(corsService);

         router.attach("/xyz", XYZ.class);
    }
}
```

Server Resource which handles and returns a JSON Representation

```
public class XYZ extends ServerResource {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("API:Xyz");

    @Get(":json")
    public Representation handleGetRequest() {
         ..
         return new JsonRepresentation("{\"code\": 4008, \"description\": \"Something blah something\"}");
    }
}
```

**Is there something I am doing wrong ?**

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your servlet configuration file as explained in document (below link).
I think servlet is not bound to a class.

https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/editions/gae

Update

Ok so if you deeper in documentation :
https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.0/jee/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.html
https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.0/jee/api/org/restlet/Component.html 
You can see that component is optional but can be usefull, but maybe in GAE implementation it doesn't have one by default.

Comment: yes I did. I followed it by the book. Funny part is I am running it without issues, but these logs freak me out